# Assign value from Oracle SQL statement to PHP variable

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to create a PHP page that will run a SQL select statement that returns 1 row and take the values in two of the columns to PHP variables but I am getting the error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: firstname

Here is what the important part of my code looks like:

```
$sql = " select * from employee e where e.emp_id = 123";

echo $sql;

$stid = oci_parse($Conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);
oci_fetch_all($stid, $res, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);

var_dump($res);

$firstname = $res['firstname'];
```

Any idea what can be causing this?

Comment: This doesn't look like it would return just one row. What does the `var_dump($res);` give you?

Comment: Hi @digitalChris - this will return just one row, I forgot the where clause in the original post

Comment: I suspect Oracle would return column names in uppercase. Try `$res['FIRSTNAME']`

Comment: [Look at the syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php) for `oci_fetch_all` What happens when you `var_dump($res)`?

Comment: I get back a two dimensional array?

Comment: Thank you @mustaccio, I tried uppercase but it still did not work

Comment: You are returning a multi-dimensional array, yet treating it like a simple array. I'd expect a table containing one row to be returned by your query. Even if you are returning a table of one row, it's still a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: I had to add [0] after the column:

```
$firstname = $res['firstname'][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check by this code

```
$firstname = $res[0]['firstname'];
```

Comment: Thank you - this was VERY close